# Redirecting based on login conditions in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Im using active directory windows authentication to check if a user is loged in.

The client side code is in Angular the server side is in C#. How can I get angular to check if a user is authorized when trying to connect to a page, and redirect based on privileges.

Everything ive seen online on this subject is overly complex. I dont need it to be secure, I just want a simple solution. Is there some kind of listener for route changes?

#### Explain to me like im completely new to angular and javascript

Answer (score 0):

If your C# app is using session cookies then you can have angular do a $http() request to a C# service that can return a logged in/logged out status (1 or 0) as well as a location to redirect to if not logged in or if the user's group is foo or whatever your need is.
In your angular controller it would look something like this:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/validationURL'})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if(data.loggedIn){
            $location.path(data.redirectTo); // logged in
        }else{
            $location.path('/'); // not logged in
        }
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $location.path('/');
    });
```

Your '/validationURL' script would return something like:

```
{
    "loggedIn":true,
    "redirectTo": "/validatedURL"
}
```